# How to solve mibble.MibLoaderException

Tags: parsing, snmp, net-snmp, mib, snmp4j

I want to parse some mibs via mibble. Some of them can be parsed successfully. But when I try to parse two files named NS-TRAPS.mib and mib-jnx-chassis.txt for juniper device. It always get exceptions.

```
net.percederberg.mibble.MibLoaderException: found 1 MIB loader errors

    at net.percederberg.mibble.MibLoader.load(MibLoader.java:539)
    at net.percederberg.mibble.MibLoader.load(MibLoader.java:466)
```

For mibble source code, I can just follow MibLoader.parseMib. I found when it go parser.parse() in parseMib function, exceptions throwed. I cannot step into parse function since I have no mibble parser source code. 
Further more, for this two mib files, I can compile successfully through OidView. I have no idea what caused this problem.

How can I solve this exception? Is there any workaround solution for this problem?

Any suggestion is welcome. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the parser is not able not resolve MIB dependencies. Check **IMPORTS** in your MIB files. In general you should put all dependencies (MIB files) to the same folder so the parser can find them.

Comment: I have stepped into parse function today. I find the root cause of parse error is both of two MIBs missed a comma at the end of SYNTAX line. Now it works. Thank you all the same. I am new to SNMP. You give me much help.